# Modal is showing and immediately disappearing

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code where the `#delcomm` modal is showing and immediately disappearing:

```js
$('.post').find('.interaction').find('#cid').on('click', function(event) {
  // comid = event.target.dataset['commid'];
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#delcomm').modal();
  comid = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];
  $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: urlDel,
      data: {
        com_id: comid,
        pos_id: $('#pid').val(),
        _token: token
      }
    })
    .done(function(msg) {
      $('#delcomm').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

Comment: that means the ajax request is completed quickly

Comment: how can I slow it down ?

Comment: can use setInterval (For example 2 seconds) in that way it will hide two seconds after ajax request is completed

Comment: shall I add that as answer?

Comment: Why not use something less intrusive if the flashing modal is an issue? A spinner next to the element which triggered the request, for example

Comment: Is there a way to split the showing and the posting ? I think that way it might only disappear after I submit

Comment: Try to add setInterval for "$('#delcomm').modal('hide');"

Comment: Slowing down the responsiveness of your site because of the UI sounds like a really bad idea to me.

Comment: Agree and basically there is more chance for the model to get hide later if real world traffic take place.

Comment: better can use CSS Animations to get correct responsive model

Comment: Can you please share your code on snippet?

Comment: You are hiding the model, $('#delcomm').modal('hide'); Remove it it will not hide. instead of use $('#delcomm').modal('show'); to show model after ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code

```
$('.post').find('.interaction').find('#cid').on('click', function(event) {
  // comid = event.target.dataset['commid'];
  event.preventDefault();
  comid = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];
  $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: urlDel,
      data: {
        com_id: comid,
        pos_id: $('#pid').val(),
        _token: token
      }
    })
    .done(function(msg) {
      $('#delcomm').modal('show');
    });
});
```